# 8 GB on MacBook Pro (13", 2.26 ghz)

Tags: memory

The Apple specs say the 13" MacBook Pro supports up to 8GB of RAM. I have a 2.26GHz 13" one, and would really want to use this.

Has anyone tried this before? What is the maximum memory recommended, to be "safe"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a 2.4-GHz 13-inch MacBook Pro, which is virtually the same as your model. It has 8GB of RAM. No problems thus far.

Comment: Great! 8GB, here I come...

Comment: +agreed... should be no problems whatsoever as long as the memory isn't radically different from what your machine can handle

Comment: Any suggested brands for Apple compatible RAM or at least a preference?

Comment: @Ryan Wersal: Hmm... Not really, to be honest. I usually get Corsair, Crucial, G.SKILL, or Mushkin.